# Why is HTML5 video timestamp in hours:min:sec for a 50 second video?

Tags: html, html5-video, embedded-video

I have a basic HTML5 video player with a video from my server. The problem is the timestamp. It's displaying as

`470:58:14 / 470:58:21`

I've never seen this before and I can't find documentation as to why it might happen.

**HTML**

```
<video controls controlsList="nodownload" poster="img/wallpaper.jpg" preload="none">
  <source src="videos/title.webm" type="video/webm" />
  <source src="video/title.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  <source src="video/title.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 video. Please use Chrome, Firefox, Edge or Safari to view this content.</p>
</video>
```

**Timestamp**

[image: timestamp in hrs:min:sec]

Comment: Probably the browser is unable to parse the real duration of the media and defaults to some very high value (check the video `.duration` property, might be `Infinite`)

Comment: It was something like that. I toyed around with the order of the video types. Original order was `webm, ogg, mp4`. I switched them around to `mp4, ogg, webm`, and it is working fine now.